# Error running Maven classworlds-1.1.pom.lastUpdated corrupted

Tags: eclipse, maven, netbeans

I'm french so i will try to have a good orthograph,

When I run my project Maven I have this error (I don't found how to do newlines) :

```
 [WARNING] Failed to canonicalize path
 C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\classworlds\classworlds\1.1\classworlds-1.1.pom.lastUpdated:
 The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable 
[WARNING] Failed to
 canonicalize path
 C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\classworlds\classworlds\1.1\classworlds-1.1.pom.lastUpdated:
 The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable [WARNING] Failed to
 write tracking file
 C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\classworlds\classworlds\1.1\classworlds-1.1.pom.lastUpdated
 java.io.FileNotFoundException:
 C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\classworlds\classworlds\1.1\classworlds-1.1.pom.lastUpdated
 (The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable)
BUILD FAILURE
```

I tried with Eclipse and Netbeans, and i removed the repertory classworlds unless results

In the SpringGardenApplication.java file :

```
 package org.yannart.springgarden;

 import
 org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

 /**  * Classe qui initialise l'application SpringGarden.  */ public
 class SpringGardenApplication {

    /**      * Methode main ou commence le flux de l'application.    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Demarre le contexte de Spring        new
 ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml",
                SpringGardenApplication.class);     } }
```

In the web.xml file :

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>   <display-name>Archetype Created Web
Application</display-name> </web-app>
```

In the applicationContext.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- ANNOTATIONS POUR L'INJECTION DE DEPENDANCES -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- ANNOTATIONS POUR LA CREATION DE BEANS -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.yannart.springgarden" />

    <!-- ANNOTATIONS POUR AOP -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

        <!-- JARDINIER -->
    <bean id="jardinier" class="org.yannart.springgarden.Jardinier" p:nom="Dupond" />

        <!--PLANTES -->
    <bean id="tomate" parent="plante" scope="prototype" p:nomPlante="Tomate" />
    <bean id="patate" parent="plante" scope="prototype" p:nomPlante="Patate" />
    <bean id="choux" parent="plante" scope="prototype" p:nomPlante="Choux" />
    <bean id="pomme" parent="plante" scope="prototype" p:nomPlante="Pomme" />
    <bean id="poire" parent="plante" scope="prototype" p:nomPlante="Poire" />
    <bean id="poireMalade" parent="plante" scope="prototype" p:nomPlante="PoireMalade" />
    <bean id="patateMalade" parent="plante" scope="prototype" p:nomPlante="PatateMalade" />

        <!-- POTAGER -->
    <bean id="potager" class="org.yannart.springgarden.Parcelle"
        init-method="melanger">
        <property name="nom" value="Potager" />
        <property name="plantes">
            <list>
                <ref bean="tomate" />
                <ref bean="patate" />
                <ref bean="patateMalade" />
                <ref bean="choux" />
                <ref bean="choux" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- VERGER -->
    <bean id="verger" class="org.yannart.springgarden.Parcelle"
        init-method="melanger">
        <property name="nom" value="Verger" />
        <property name="plantes">
            <list>
                <ref bean="pomme" />
                <ref bean="poireMalade" />
                <ref bean="poire" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

            <!-- JARDIN -->
    <bean id="jardin" class="org.yannart.springgarden.Jardin" init-method="jardiner">
        <property name="jardinier" ref="jardinier" />
        <property name="parcelles">
            <list>
                <ref bean="potager" />
                <ref bean="verger" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <!-- Les doses sont aléatoires -->
        <property name="doseEau" value="#{ T(java.lang.Math).random() * 100 }" />
        <property name="doseEngrais" value="#{ T(java.lang.Math).random() * 50 }" />
    </bean>
```

Furthermore, when I delete the repertory "repository" in the repertory ".m2" the repertory "1.1" is always here and apparently corrupted

Do you have an idea?
Thanks

Comment: And what is your project? You need to post some codes to let us see before we can help.

Comment: Thank you for your response, what is the code's part will be interesting? I have a file application.xml, pom.xml and some classes and interfaces, I followed this tutorial :http://yannart.developpez.com/java/spring/tutoriel/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem comes from the cache. Have you tried to delete the entire content of .m2/repository/ ?

Try to stop the server and maven before deleting.
If you are with Netbeans, you can see servers :
[image]

If there is some process locked, you can kill it directly or reboot your pc.

Comment: Hello, i reboot computer but impossible to delete .m2/repository/ because of repertory m2/repository/classworlds/classworlds/1.1

Comment: Maybe a solution would be to point an other repertory maven but i don't know how to do with Netbeans

Comment: Yes, don't think you can do it with Netbeans because it's about the maven installation. But I think the better to remove the repository corrupted. Have you try to boot with safe mode (mode sans echec)?

Comment: yes I have tried safe mode (impossible to be in this mode... My computer contains certainly a lot of virus...)

Comment: I will try on an other PC

Comment: I functions with an other PC